# How can I read lines in from a CSV file, and add to them in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to read in from a CSV file a file path name, but then I need to append that file path with ".V2", delete the files, and then again with ".V6" added and delete the files.

Basically, deleting profile paths and each user has \adpath\user.name.V2 AND \adpath\user.name.v6

The CSV file contains \adpath\user.name
Currently, I have:

$

```
Users = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Leavers.csv'
$samAccountName = $Users.SamAccountName
$string1 = $Users.ProfilePath
$V2=".V2"
$V6=".V6"

foreach( $User in $Users ){
       $profilepathv2 = $String1+$V2
       if (Test-Path $profilepathv2){
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv2 Path Found"
       Remove-Item ($profilepathv2)-Force -Confirm:$false
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv2 - has been deleted"
       }
       Else{
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V2 Path Not found - Skipped"
       }
       $profilepathV6 = $string1+$V6
       if (Test-Path $profilepathv6){
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv6 Path Found"
       Remove-Item ($profilepathv6)-Force -Confirm:$false
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv6 - has been deleted"
       }
       Else{
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V6 Path Not found - Skipped"
        }
    }
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black "Profiles deleted"
```

However, all it does is seem to append the last name read in with a space and then .V2 or .V6 - meaning nothing gets deleted. This is the output:

```
\\ad.domain.co.uk\dfs\Path1\PupilProfiles\Joe.Bloggs
\\ad.domain.co.uk\dfs\Path1\PupilProfiles\Jane.Doe
\\ad.domain.co.uk\dfs\Path1\PupilProfiles\John.Doe .V6 has been deleted
```

How can I cycle through the CSV, append the .V2 and .V6 with no space, and delete the profile folder? I am missing something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build the target path inside the loop. ... like this:

```
Users = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Leavers.csv'
$V2 = '.V2'
$V6 = '.V6'

foreach ( $User in $Users ) {
    $profilepathv2 = $User.ProfilePath + $V2
    if (Test-Path $profilepathv2) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv2 Path Found"
        Remove-Item $profilepathv2 -Force -Recurse
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv2 - has been deleted"
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V2 Path Not found - Skipped"
    }
    $profilepathV6 = $User.ProfilePath + $V6
    if (Test-Path $profilepathv6) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$profilepathv6 Path Found"
        Remove-Item $profilepathv6 -Force -Recurse
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$profilepathv6 - has been deleted"
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ".V6 Path Not found - Skipped"
    }
}
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black "Profiles deleted"
```

The spaces you get might come from your CSV file. You should check this. If this is the case you can add a `.trim()` method to the variable to get rid of the additional unwanted space charachter.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting this wrapped round my head so tightly, I just couldn't get it!